# Tricky mod rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I hope someone can help me, I am looking to help an ex-client with some troubles.

they have images from URL's with this sub-sub structure:

http://images.abc1234.SPECIFIC-DOMAIN.com/image.jpg

Due to a long story I do not completely understand, that sub sub structure exists and now is in peril.

Can anyone point to a solution to rewrite the above into:

http://images.ANOTHER-DOMAIN.com/image.jpg

which would also NOT AFFECT something like this:

images.THIRD-DOMAIN.com/image.jpg

Any help to this challenge would be appreciated.

Thank you and sorry if this is written in bad form, it's not my area of expertise.

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will redirect:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^images.abc1234.SPECIFIC-DOMAIN.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.(jpg|png|gif))$ http://images.ANOTHER-DOMAIN.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. One additonal layer to add question, if you know, is there some way to make your answer fit a scenario where there are multiple sub subs (image.abc124.SPECIFIC_DOMAIN.com & image.zyx1234.SPECIFIC-DOMAIN.com & etc...) with out having seperate rules for each?  Thank you.

Comment: Try `^images.[^\.]+.SPECIFIC-DOMAIN.com$` as regex for host instead